# Using Article format and changing geometry from page to page

Tags: geometry, documentclass

I am using the `documentclass` article and would like to keep it but I would like to change the page-geometry for every page on the right side (like in a book) to avoid having text in the link. Is there a simple command for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have `twoside` option of `article`.

Answer (score 1):

As @JouleV said, `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` do the job. If you want something more extreme, you can use `changepage` package to detect if a page is even or odd. For example, the following code

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\if\ifoddpage
    \newgeometry{left=7cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\else
    \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=7cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\fi


\begin{document}

\section{Odd Page}
\lipsum[2-4]

\newpage

\section{Even Page}
\lipsum[2-4]

\newpage

\section{Amnother Odd Page}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

Produces a radical change between even and odd pages, this could be useful for other purposes, so I give it as an answer, even if the right answer was already given by @JoulV in the comment.